# Downloading SVG URL image, on a button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using file-saver, npm package to download SVG URL image, which I display on one of my pages, but on Firefox and older chrome versions when I press the button to download the image, I'm being redirect instead of downloading the image

Comment: Please explain briefly about your problem and add some code snippets or screenshots of errors.

Answer (score 0):

The native way would be to use the [`Content-Disposition` HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) to instruct browsers to trigger file download instead of showing the content. For example:

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.svg"

For the download links, you should also set the [`download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes). This will prevent navigation to a resource. It will start a download instead.

For legacy IE, you may fallback to use [`navigator.msSaveBlob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/msSaveBlob) to trigger a manual download of a prepared Blob (you must first download the contents, then convert it to a Blob object so IE can save the result).